# Feynman diagrams: Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/empty dot' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, tikz-styles, tikz-feynman, feynman

I am trying to draw a specific feynman diagram using tikz-feynman. It plots it almost correctly apart from the fact that I get this error

> Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/empty dot' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

And the empty dot has lines crossing inside it as you  can see in the following image:

[image]

My code is this:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,border={1pt 1pt 16pt 1pt},varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage[top=12mm,bottom=12mm,left=30mm,right=30mm,head=12mm,includeheadfoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx,color,soul}
\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}
\usepackage{XCharter}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{figure*}[t]
    \hspace{-0.4cm}\feynmandiagram [scale=.7,horizontal=root to v0] {
         root -- [fermion] v0, 
         v0 -- [fermion] v1, 
         v0 -- [fermion] v4, 
         v1 -- [fermion] v2, 
         v1 -- [fermion] vNone0, 
         v2 -- [fermion] v3 [empty dot], 
         v2 -- [fermion] vNone1, 
         v4 -- [fermion] v3 [empty dot], 
         v4 -- [fermion] vNone2, 
     }; 
\end{figure*} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: you can use `[/tikzfeynman/empty dot]` and the error goes but the lines still overlap the circle

Comment: thank you!! The error was the most annoying part. Any ideas for the overlap with the circle?

Comment: no idea but someone who knows tikz better may come by....

Comment: You can remove the second option `empty dot`, which will also solve the error. The overlapping seems to be a result of scaling.

Comment: What do you mean remove the second option empty dot? For the scaling: for scale 1.0 the problem is solved by the graph becomes too 'empty'. Ideally I would like to keep it 0.7 scale

Comment: I mean that you just remove the second `[emtpy dot]`. Since you already assigned the node at `v3` this option two lines before, there is no need to do it again. Would the option `small` work instead of `scale=.7`?

Comment: small makes it work! Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: You can also try `node distance=1cm`.

Comment: node distance=1cm makes the diagram too clustered. But I will use the 'small' option because it is general enough to be used for other graphs. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not totally sure why this is, but the error goes away if you remove the second `[emtpy dot]` statement, probably because at this position, no new node is constructed, but the already existing node `v3` is referenced.

To solve the problem that the lines of the edges point inside the dot, you can use the option `small` instead of `scale=0.7` or, if this is not small enough, reduce the `node distance` (or even combine this with `small`):

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}

\begin{document}
    \feynmandiagram [horizontal=root to v0, small] {
        root -- [fermion] v0, 
        v0 -- [fermion] v1, 
        v0 -- [fermion] v4, 
        v1 -- [fermion] v2, 
        v1 -- [fermion] vNone0, 
        v2 -- [fermion] v3 [empty dot], 
        v2 -- [fermion] vNone1, 
        v4 -- [fermion] v3, 
        v4 -- [fermion] vNone2, 
    }; 

    \feynmandiagram [horizontal=root to v0, node distance=1cm] {
        root -- [fermion] v0, 
        v0 -- [fermion] v1, 
        v0 -- [fermion] v4, 
        v1 -- [fermion] v2, 
        v1 -- [fermion] vNone0, 
        v2 -- [fermion] v3 [empty dot], 
        v2 -- [fermion] vNone1, 
        v4 -- [fermion] v3, 
        v4 -- [fermion] vNone2, 
    }; 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The graphs library doesn't seem to like scaling. However, `tikz-feynman` offers three keys to *scale* the diagram (by setting various different sizes to an appropriate value):

- `large`,
- `medium` (default) and
- `small`.

I suggest defining a `smaller` style in the same manner by dividing the values of `small` by 1.5 and then adjusting the values again so that the diagram looks good enough. For example, just dividing the arrow size by 1.5 led to very small arrow tips.

Feel free to adjust the values further or define your own styles in the same manner.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}
\tikzfeynmanset{
  smaller/.style={/tikzfeynman/every smaller@@},
  every smaller/.style={/tikzfeynman/every smaller@@/.append style={#1}},
  every smaller@@/.style={
    /tikz/node distance=+.6666cm,
    /graph drawing/node distance=+.83333cm,
    /graph drawing/level distance=+.6666cm,
    /graph drawing/sibling distance=+1cm,
    /tikzfeynman/every dot@@/.append style={/tikz/minimum size=+1mm},
    /tikzfeynman/every crossed dot@@/.append style={/tikz/minimum size=+1.3333mm},
    /tikzfeynman/every blob@@/.append style={/tikz/minimum size=+.3333cm},
    /tikzfeynman/arrow size=+1pt,
    /tikzfeynman/insertion/size=+1.7pt}}
\begin{document}
\feynmandiagram [scale=.7, red, horizontal=root to v0] {
   root -- [fermion] v0
        -- [fermion] {v1,             v4},
     v1 -- [fermion] {v2,             vNone0}, 
     v2 -- [fermion] {v3 [empty dot], vNone1}, 
     v4 -- [fermion] {v3,             vNone2}
 }; 
\feynmandiagram [horizontal=root to v0] {% normal size: medium
   root -- [fermion] v0
        -- [fermion] {v1,             v4},
     v1 -- [fermion] {v2,             vNone0}, 
     v2 -- [fermion] {v3 [empty dot], vNone1}, 
     v4 -- [fermion] {v3,             vNone2}
 }; 
 \feynmandiagram [small, horizontal=root to v0] {
   root -- [fermion] v0
        -- [fermion] {v1,             v4},
     v1 -- [fermion] {v2,             vNone0}, 
     v2 -- [fermion] {v3 [empty dot], vNone1}, 
     v4 -- [fermion] {v3,             vNone2}
 }; 
 \feynmandiagram [smaller, horizontal'=root to v0] {
   root -- [fermion] v0
        -- [fermion] {v1,             v4},
     v1 -- [fermion] {v2,             vNone0}, 
     v2 -- [fermion] {v3 [empty dot], vNone1}, 
     v4 -- [fermion] {v3,             vNone2}
 }; 
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]
[image]